# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to save my merged dataframe into a CSV file. As soon as the code hits on the "data.to_csv" line, it breaks. My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os,errno
import glob


print ("Path has been read successfully")
path1 = glob.glob('S:\*Data\*Files\*Raw Data\*CPU\*Perf\*YesterdayDataset*.xlsx')
print (path1)
path2 = glob.glob("S:\*Data\*Files\*Raw Data\*CPU\*Perf\*CPUPerf_201920.csv")
print ("Path has been read successfully")
print ("Action has been completed successfully")

data = []

for df in path1:
    df = pd.read_excel(df)  
    data.append(df)

data.to_csv("H:\\test1.csv", index = False)



def sremove():
    try:
        os.remove()
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.ENOENT:
            raise
```

The error I'm receiving after executing this code is:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Any help on that will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: your `data` is a list of `pd.Dataframe` instead of one `pd.Dataframe`. Try to "merge" them together first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your `data` object is a `list` of the DataFrames.  You can either convert the DataFrames individually, e.g. `df.to_csv(...)` or merge them together and output as one file.

Try changing this part:

```
data = []

for df in path1:
    df = pd.read_excel(df)  
    data.append(df)

data.to_csv("H:\\test1.csv", index = False)
```

To this:

```
df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(fl) for fl in path1)
df.to_csv("H:\\test1.csv", index = False)
```

Answer (score 2):

your problem is that you have a list of data frames and you are calling to_csv on the whole list instead of the individual data frames. Two options here, if the list only has one data frame in it, use this code:

```
data[0].to_csv("H:\\test1.csv", index = False)
```

if it has multiple data frames in it, do this:

```
for i in data:
    i.to_csv("filename", index = False)
```

bear in mind that for the second option you will need to make your filenames dynamic to avoid overwriting.

EDIT:

Misread your question. You need to actually merge the data frames

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(path1)
df2 = pd.read_execl(path2)

df = df1.merge(df2, how = 'inner', on = 'JoinField')
df.to_csv("H:\\test1.csv", index = False)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in my case I have to merge multiple files together. The inner join is not ideal, as I'll need to visualise my data later in the script's code

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use `to_csv()` function on a `list` and not on a dataframe. You have to merge your x dataframes to a single dataframe before you generate a csv from it.

Try something like this :

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os,errno
import glob


print ("Path has been read successfully")
path1 = glob.glob('S:\*Data\*Files\*Raw Data\*CPU\*Perf\*YesterdayDataset*.xlsx')
print (path1)
path2 = glob.glob("S:\*Data\*Files\*Raw Data\*CPU\*Perf\*CPUPerf_201920.csv")
print ("Path has been read successfully")
print ("Action has been completed successfully")

data = []

for df in path1:
    df = pd.read_excel(df)  
    data.append(df)


finaldf = pd.concat(data, axis=1, join='inner').sort_index()
finaldf.to_csv("H:\\test1.csv", index = False)



def sremove():
    try:
        os.remove()
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.ENOENT:
            raise
```

Comment: Beat me to it! This is exactly the problem. You're creating a list of DataFrames. You need to pd.concat them into one,

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in my case the inner join is not ideal, as I'll need to visualise my data later in the script's code

Answer (score 0):

fwiw, I had a similar issue when attempting to create a copy of a dataframe.

```
df_copy = df[uids + ['id', 'name']].copy 
vs
df_copy = df[uids + ['id', 'name']].copy()
```

Leaving the "()" off of the function call resulted in a list of dataframes and I received the same error as OP

Comment: Hmmm that's interesting - Have you tried r.ooks method (marked best answer) as shown below? It is also worth posting your answer as a question on StackOverflow as other people might have experienced the same issue as you.