# list' object has no attribute 'to_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I hve a dataframe where I want to use the group by function for Region column.It works fine in data frame
I am doing

```
import pandas as pd
#df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\mobeen\Downloads\pminus.csv')
df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\final.csv')
print(df)
df1=[v for k, v in df.groupby('region')]
df1
df1.to_csv('filename2',na_rep='Nan',index=False)
```

but after that I want to write the output in csv and it throws following error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

How can I write it into csv?
I already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59073984/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-to-csv) but it is not working

Comment: where you calling to_csv? i dont see the code for that

Comment: You need to use df1.to_csv instead

Comment: @rv.kvetch sorry for not asking question properly. I have updated the Question

Comment: I don't really understand the answers to this question. The problem is that `df1` is a _list_, not a data frame, so obviously it has no `to_csv` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting subgroup to list, you can try loop the list and export them to csv by appending

```py
dfs = [v for k, v in df.groupby('region')]

for df in dfs:
    df.to_csv('filename2', mode='a', na_rep='Nan', index=False)
```

Comment: when I write it in csv it add some additional lines. in data frame there are 473988 rows but in csv there is 474013 rows. why it is like this?

Comment: I got it it is header, which is repeating

Comment: @Katja You can try add `header=False` when exporting.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `to_csv` from the module (in `pd.to_csv(df1,'filename2',na_rep='Nan',index=False)`. Call `df1.to_csv('filename2',na_rep='Nan',index=False)`, as that is the actual dataframe.

Comment: in df1 my groupby is saved. if I call df then column is not groupby in csv

Comment: Call it from whatever csv you want to save. I was just pointing out that you were calling it at the module level. Edited to change df --> df1 in the call

Answer (score 0):

Although your code does not show you calling `to_csv()`, the error suggests that you're calling the function directly on the pandas module, i.e. `pd.to_csv()`. You should call the function on the *dataframe*, like so: `df.to_csv(filename)`.